# Approximating pi with the Monte Carlo method gives suprisingly accurate results

Tags: python, statistics, pi

I am trying to apply the Monte Carlo method to obtain an approximate value of π but I am a little surprised by the results I obtained because it seemed to me that with 539,354 points drawn, I was supposed to get an approximate value of π to within 10<sup>–2</sup>. But I get much better precision and so I wonder if I made a mistake somewhere in my code or if it actually takes fewer draws to get an accuracy of one hundredth.

Here is my Python code:

```
from random import random
from math import pi
import numpy
from numpy.random import rand
 
 
def simulX():
    x, y = random(), random()
    return int(x**2 + y**2 <= 1)
 
def calculer_Sn(n=1000):
    x = rand(n)
    y = rand(n)
    return numpy.sum(x**2 + y**2 <= 1)
 
def calculer_Pn(n=1000):
    return 4 * calculer_Sn(n) / n
 
def approxpi():
    return calculer_Pn(539354)
 
print(sum(abs(approxpi() - pi) for x in range(1000)) / 1000)
```

Over 1000 tests, we obtain, probably, on average, a deviation from π very much lower than 10<sup>–2</sup>.

Comment: Essentially you're sampling a binomial distribution (a point is either in the unit circle or it isn't) where the "success" probability `p` is π/4. The standard error of your result for `n` trials is `sqrt(p * (1-p) / n)` (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176757/why-does-the-standard-error-of-hat-p-sqrtp1-p-n). For n=539354, that gives a standard error about 0.00056. So yes, it's overwhelmingly likely that you get within 0.01 of the true π.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I compute the mean difference between pi and the estimated value for 1000 trials, I normally get a value about 0.002. Is it realistic ?

Comment: What are you running to get that number? I can't replicate it - when I run the code in your question (except delete the 53954 and let the `calculer_Pn` function take its default argument of 1000), I get numbers of about 0.04. That's about what would be expected - if `n=1000`, the above formula gives a standard error of 0.013 when estimating π/4, so an error of about 0.052 when estimating π.

Comment: I only execute my code and it displayed "0.0017719478837000388" for example. It is the print that displays it (with 1 000 calls to the function approxpi but maybe you understood that it was with replacing "539354" by "1000"...).

Comment: If you run the literal code in the question, then you are averaging over 1000 "experiments", where each experiment performs 539354 binomial trials.

Comment: Do you think my code is correct ?

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean now - I think we were using different meanings of "trial". So your result is about what would be expected. Standard error with 539354 drawings is 0.00056 for the estimation of π/4. So the standard error for the estimation of π is 4* that, which is about 0.0022. When I use your code and calculate the mean squared error (i.e. `sqrt(sum((approxpi() - pi)**2 for x in range(1000)) / 1000)`) I indeed get close to 0.0022. The mean absolute error is a bit smaller (that's your 0.00178).

Comment: Okay, thank you !